# Getting runtime Error in Leetcode Valid Parentheses solution

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.

An input string is valid if:

Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
Every close bracket has a corresponding open bracket of the same type.

Example 1:

Input: s = "()"
Output: true
Example 2:

Input: s = "()[]{}"
Output: true
Example 3:

Input: s = "(]"
Output: false

Constraints:

1 <= s.length <= 104
s consists of parentheses only '()[]{}'.

```
class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    def isBalanced(s):
        dict_mapping = {'}': '{', ')': '(', ']': '['}
        open_stack = []

        for char in s:
            if char in dict_mapping.values():
                open_stack.append(char)
            elif char in dict_mapping.keys():
                if not open_stack or open_stack.pop() != dict_mapping[char]:
                    return False
            else:
                # Handle characters other than parentheses, braces, and brackets
                return False

        return len(open_stack) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `open_stack[-1]` instead of `open_stack.pop()` Otherwise when you first encounter a closing bracket, you would prematurely remove the opening bracket from the stack before verifying whether the pair of brackets is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This solution iterates through the input `string s`, maintaining a stack to keep track of the opening brackets encountered. When encountering a closing bracket, it checks if it matches the corresponding opening bracket on the top of the stack. If not or if the stack is empty, it `returns False` indicating an invalid string. If the iteration completes without any issues and the stack is empty, it `returns True`, indicating a valid string.

```
def isValid(s: str) -> bool:
        stack = []
        mapping = {')': '(', '}': '{', ']': '['}
        
        for char in s:
            if char in mapping.values():
                stack.append(char)
            elif char in mapping.keys():
                if not stack or mapping[char] != stack.pop():
                    return False
            else:
                continue
        return len(stack) == 0
```

Example usage:

```
s1 = "()"
s2 = "()[]{}"
s3 = "(]"
print(isValid(s1))  # Output: True
print(isValid(s2))  # Output: True
print(isValid(s3))  # Output: False
```